# Does the Facebook Graph API work in C# 2.0?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am working on ASP.NET 2.0, where I need to retrieve a Facebook user's details upon sucessful login. On the client side, I have used the JavaScript SDK, where it functions well by clicking on the Facebook connect button. I am able to retrieve the email and other details.

On the server side, however, during page load I need to retrieve user details (first name, last name, facebook id, email, photo) without clicking on the connect button. So for that when I was searching I found that with Graph API I can do it. But all the samples provided on the internet are related to the VS 2010 Facebook C# SDK. What I would like to know is whether the Graph API is also available to C# 2.0 (VS 2005)?

If so, where can I download the same and samples for implementing the same please?

Thanks,
Sarvesh M

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this yourself - even without the use of the C# Facebook SDK if you wanted to. When you call the GraphAPI via a URL like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=URL_TO_YOUR_PAGE_WITH_COMMENTS_ON_HERE
```

-- the resulting response is a Json result (containing all your comments, users, IDs, photos, likes etc.) which you can parse (using .NET) and then do whatever you want with the resultant data.

If you have to use .NET 2.0, then you can grab the very handy [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com) library (I believe version 1.3 works with .NET 2.0) to deserialize the data returned from the graph API for you.

Like you say, if you can't use the C# Facebook SDK, you can use the WebRequest and WebResponse classes from .NET to programmatically hit the graph API URL (mentioned above), get the JSON response (from the WebResponse object) and finally deserialize it (using JSon.Net 1.3) ready to use in your application.